# Usage of interceptor in ngOnInit in ssr build - Angular 8

Tags: angular, interceptor, angular8, angular-universal

I am using interceptors for adding api headers. and i call some apis in ngOnInit function. For normal ng serve it is working perfectly. but in ssr build and serve, the api does not called and the page does not rendered but shows loading. If i commented the api call in ngOnInit it works. How can i solve this problem?? Please help.

My component.ts function

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authController.fetchUser
      .subscribe(
        (params) => {
          this.id = +params['id'];
          this.user = this.authController.getUser(this.id)
        }
      );
  }
```

the fetchUser() is a api call function uses interceptor.
this function does not works in ssr build.

Comment: Edit questrion and show code exactly what you were try till now.

Comment: Any error in the console where you started ssr from?

Comment: You should get the data on the server using nodejs and then provide it for the ss-render. Or you can use mock data for ssr.

Comment: what is `fetchUser` doing, would you please add that code

Comment: `fetchUser` is an API call. it fetch the data from api

Comment: @David there is no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the scenario seems like you are using something related to client side in the SSR code, that is reason your API is not getting called and keeps loading.

While using SSR it is always a good approach to keep platformBrowser check in the code, just change the code like below -

```
 constructor(private router: Router) { }

 ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.fetchData();
    }
  }

  fetchData() {
    this.authController.fetchUser
      .subscribe((params) => {
        this.id = +params['id'];
        this.user = this.authController.getUser(this.id)
      });
  }
```

Comment: i call the function in a button click it works fine. but call it in ngOnInit it does n't works.